# Given how Obito had acquired Bijuu in the past, why would he bother going to war?

Tags: naruto

I don't get this.

Did Obito think that it would be easier to go to war with the whole shinobi world rather than capture the 8-tails and 9-tails Jinchuuriki on the low like how he did with the other ones?  He basically ended up fighting not only both of them but also the entire shinobi world.

Would Obito's plans succeeded if he did not declare war and kept everything under the radar till the end?  I believe he'd have been successful and that he wouldn't have needed to summon Madara at all.

Comment: He went to war with the whole Shinobi world in order IN ORDER TO capture 8 and 9 tails. He could not do the same method like in other Jinchuuriki because: both are quite powerful and both are already under the protection of the Alliance (they were also mobile all the time). If he could get under their 'radar', he would probably do so but seeing as he did not, that just means that he either saw their protection as powerful or that it would be easier to take the alliance out of the way first or use them as bait, knowing how Naruto responds to that kinds of situations.

Answer (score 2):

Obito declared war because he knew that the alliance would keep Bee & Naruto at a disclosed location since they had caught on to what the Akatsuki were doing. The war would allow him to draw out Naruto & Bee to complete the plan of bringing back Ten Tails in it's prime state.

He had Kisame gather intel, but then of course Kabuto showed up. Obito's plan was essentially to gather intel on the locations of the last two jinchuuriki, use the zetsu to distract the allied shinobi forces in a war, and lure Naruto/Bee out. It didn't work out like that, but he had a legit plan.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed his plan would be a success if he kept it on the low but since bee was like a brother to the Raikage when he thought he was kidnapped he couldn't take it and since he knew it was an Uchiha with the Akatsuki who took him he called for that meeting (the kages summit) where they were going to discuss what to do against this organization especially with Konoha also been destroyed by pain, so Obito knew they he couldn't work on the low anymore that he had to step up and threaten them to declare war if they don't give up hachibi and Kyuubi and that's how the war started.
and of course, it was also for his own benefit since cuz like this he can lure naruto out.
But the part about summoning Madara, it's not a need, it's a deal, it was planed like this.
the original deal was to make Nagato resurrect Madara so that Obito can also fall in that ultimat genjutsu to be with Rin and kinda live his deepest desires happily ever after, but that also didn't when Nagato died and Kabuto summoned Madara in that form